# toString using generic variables?

Tags: java, generics, tostring

So there I have this Bag class here, to which I added a `remove(T x)` method, and now I want to print this, I know I have to use the `toString()` method but I keep getting either compilation error or still getting the hash code of the object `b`... there is my interpretation of this but still doesn't work, my solution (the particular) gives me error on the `return bag[i]` line :(

```
class Bag<T> {// generic class with T standing for a class

    private T[] bag =(T[])(new Object[100]);                 
    private int numElements = 0; // junk in bag[numElements..] 

    void add(T x) { // put x in bag
            bag[numElements] = x; numElements++;
    }

    void remove (T x){
        if(x!=null && numElements>0){
            for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
                if(bag[i]==x){
                    bag[i]=bag[numElements];
                    numElements-=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    int freq(T x) { // how many x’s in bag?
            int count = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<numElements; i++)
                if (bag[i].equals(x)) // .equals because T a class 
                    count++;
            return count;
    }

    public String toString(){
        for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
            return bag[i];
        }
    }
}

class GenericExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Bag<String> b = new Bag<String>();
        b.add("cat"); b.add("dog"); b.add("cat"); 

    }
}
```

I also tried typing `String.valueOf(bag[i])`but still had compilation error... Why is there a problem anyway? In this example the T is a String so I can't understand why it's doing that..

Comment: Why are you trying to return multiple times? Doesn't really work like that. What exactly were trying to accomplish with that loop?

Comment: @peeskillet I was trying to print a long string of the contents of the array :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do like this

```
public String toString(){
    return Arrays.toString(bag);
}
```

Comment: didn't work :( I get this message: `GenericExample.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
return Arrays.toString(bag);
        
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class Bag<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Bag
Note: GenericExample.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error`

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski Please add this line  import java.util.Arrays; in your import.

Comment: Bingo :D It works but what I get is pretty funny :P
[cat, dog, cat, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ...]

Comment: @ChrisDobkowski this  new Object[100] line will create 100 fixed memory that will initially filled with null values. You try to use ArrayList.

Comment: I would if I could :P But it's a fixed exercise and it uses arrays for this example :(

Answer (score 4):

You want to change the toString method maybe in the following:

```
public String toString(){
    return Arrays.toString(bag);        
}
```

OR the home brew version

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
        sb.append(bag[i]);
    }        
    return sb.toString();
}
```

If the object you put into your bag does not override toString, then you get a string of hashcodes.

Answer (score 2):

What about using [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
public String toString(){
    return Arrays.toString(bag);
}
```

Comment: I see in an other comment that you were missing an import.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return an Object when String is expected.

Use `return bag[i].toString()`

Also

```
public String toString(){
    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
        return bag[i];
    }
}
```

You can return only once from the function. You cannot put return statement is loop. You can probably use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to append all your data in the loop and the finally call toString() on it and return from outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to return multiple times? Did you just want to concatenate all the index values like this?

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++){
        sb.append(bag[i] + ", ");
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```